# Convexifying sets defined using $\max$

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm trying to compute the convex hull of the following set as a set of linear inequalities

$$S := \left\{ \left(x,\max(0,x)\right) \mid l \leq x \leq u \right\}$$

This set is not convex given $l<0<u$. Simple geometry can lead to the solution

[image]

However, I would like to know a more general approach that I could, for instance, apply to the following set

$$S = \left\{ (x,y,\max(x,y)) \mid l_x \leq x \leq u_x \land l_y \leq y \leq u_y \right\}$$

$$\text{Conv}(S) = \,?$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo its the set of all points (x,max(0,x)) for all x between l and u

Comment: Sure this is equivalent and probably more clear

Comment: The image is the convex set around $S$. $S$ is just the line at the bottom.